# Threads on different Hardware

Tags: java, multithreading

When I fist learned about Java threads, I've been told that, the multi threading is not real.
That is, there is a single CPU and the OS does a context switch between threads to simulate multi threading.

Nowdays, we have i3, i5 i7, dual core, core2dou and etc...

So when I have a Java program that uses a thread pool in size 10 (for example),
Assuming the thread pool is full with threads ready to run,
How many threads will run in the same time (for real) in i5 computer with 2 cores?

Answer (score 1):

At maximum there will be 2 threads executing simultaneously (2 cores), but many more may be scheduled for execution (waiting for cpu)

Comment: It is true if the JVM implementation maps its own threads on OS threads; if not, there will only be one ready OS thread (simulating many java threads as in a posix thread library implementation)

Comment: well, I've observed, that running N threads where N is the number of logical CPUs manages to utilize 100% of my CPU, so I guess it is executing them simultaneously.

Comment: Jorge is theoretically right, but there hasn't been any JVM in the last decade that didn't use native threads so in practice this answer fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning Java had 'green' threads, so the thread scheduling was done in the jvm. But since a very long time Java has native threads. In any case, Java can make use of all your cores if you provide enough threads.

PS:
If you core supports Hyper threading, than the OS will see twice the number of cores. This is useful if your thread is stalled for e.g. a memory read so another thread can run.  At home I have a 4 core Xeon machine, but with Hyperthreading enabled, my operating system will see 8 cores. But effectively only 4 threads can run concurrently.